# If a question is good enough to answer is it good enough to vote up?

Tags: discussion, questions, up-votes

I keep seeing questions with 3 to 5 answers that have a 0 score. In general if you answer the question shouldnt you up vote it as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ## *It depends.<sup><sup><sub>tm</sub></sup></sup>*

**Bad, Answerable Questions**

There's a reason a badge like [**reversal**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/reversal) exists: there *are* bad questions that deserve the downvotes they're getting, but that are nonetheless answerable. And a +20 answer on such a question is rare enough to deserve a gold badge.

**"Meh" Questions**

Voting is anonymous, and personal. People up/down vote for whatever reason they like. They can also *not vote* for the same reasons, too. If someone is new to Stack Exchange and you don't want to ruin their day because they posted the 2,478<sup>th</sup> [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) question about *Runtime Error 13* and just feel like helping out that day, it's possible that question gets answers, but upvotes? not so sure.

Comment: Didn't know about the reversal badge, good answer thanks